# When do first posts appear in the "First Posts" review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review

I have noticed that first posts sometimes do not appear immediately, or even at all, in the "First Posts" review queue.  A case in point is [72163](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72163/is-there-a-build-in-function-converting-a-quantity-to-one-with-mixed-units-such), which certainly was a first post but never appeared in the "First Posts" review queue, insofar as I could tell.  I "hovered" over the queue for ten minutes after I saw the one-minute-old post, refreshing the page every minute.  Moreover, examining when others reviewed first posts, I found no activity within the past 10 minutes.  This seems like a problem to me.

More generally, is there any way to know when any of the queues have items to review, apart from going to the review page?

Comment: Good question. I check in on the site 3-5 times per day, sometimes less, sometimes more. Read up on chat, new questions, comment a bit (given that I'm mostly using my iPad I don't provide answer often lately) and I perform some janitorial work on the queues when available. I too noticed that the First Post queue seems to be a little different. It is empty most of the time, but when I check the history several First Posts have been reviewed by others. I guess the number of reviews necessary for them is lower than others for them to be removed from the queue.

Comment: I've noticed that if I make a comment on a first post before visiting the review queue, I don't see the post in the review queue.  And I may not have noticed the times when that statement is false. :)