# When do questions appear on the "Close Vote" review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review

This morning, I noticed that question [74103](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74103/what-is-the-product-of-11-p2-over-all-primes-p) had two Close votes, and I went to the "review" page to cast my vote.  However, it was not available to me for voting.  I returned to the Question list and then to that particular question, which still had just two Close votes.  About a minute later, I returned to the "review" page, but it still was not there.  Finally, I returned to this question on the Question list, clicked on "Close" and cast my vote, which was accepted.  This, together with my earlier [question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/when-do-first-posts-appear-in-the-first-posts-review-queue) about the "First Posts" list, cause me to wonder about the completeness, or at least the timeliness, of the "review" queues.

Comment: I retagged this question for the time being.  I seem to remember reading that the review queues are not supposed to be complete; I think there are delays and other filters applied.  However I cannot find a reference at this time.  If you are curious you should try searching [Meta.SE] yourself.

Comment: Related, but not a *clear* answer to your question: [(238698)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238698/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Meta StackExchange [179386](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/close-review-queue-questions) seems to answer my question, saying questions in a person's "Close Vote" queue are selected randomly.  But, no details (e.g., what fraction are selected randomly) or explanation of "Why" are provided.  Two other relevant, informative questions: [151698](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151698/why-do-some-questions-with-reopen-votes-not-show-up-in-the-reopen-review-queue), [164288](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-post-removed-from-a-review-queue).